# Problema al cargar pagina, en sección de formulario, no aparece color background

Tags: php, html, css

Soy algo nuevo en esto del desarrollo web y tengo un problema con mi pagina al cargarla en el servidor.

Estoy creando una pagina web simple con **HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 4 y PhP**, y al subirla al servidor me da un problema con el color del background solo en la sección del formulario de contacto.

En un principio pensé que se podía deber a un conflicto entre el color de esa sección y el background-image del body, en este punto sucede algo extraño, borré de mi código la imagen de fondo del background (ya que no la necesito) y borre la imagen de los archivos de la carpeta, sin embargo, ESTA SIGUE AHÍ, ni siquiera existe en los archivos pero la imagen sigue mostrándose, lo cual escapa a mi comprensión...
Debo aclarar que antes de subirla al servidor probé la página en un localhost y en este no existe ningún conflicto con la página el color que quiero en el background del formulario se ve sin problemas, esto sólo sucede al subir la pagina al servidor.

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

adjunto código:

```css
.pacifico{
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive, sans-serif;
}
.dosis{
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
.roboto{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.zigzag-4::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(
    -45deg, transparent 33.33%,
    #E57D2A 33.33%, #E57D2A 66.66%,
    transparent 66.66%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 33.33%,
    #E57D2A 33.33%, #E57D2A 66.66%,
    transparent 66.66%);
  background-size: 30px 60px;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.texto-azul{
  color: #3511CC;
}
.bgcolor-durazno{
  background-color: rgb(229, 125, 42);
}
.boton-azul{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3511CC;
}
.boton-azul:hover{
  color: #3511CC;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton|Pacifico|Roboto:700|Dosis:800" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--MEDIOS DE CONTACTO-->
<div class="container-fluid bgcolor-durazno zigzag-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col-12 my-3">
      <h1 class="texto-azul pacifico mt-5">Cómo contactarnos</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <!--FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="texto-azul dosis">
            ¡Envíanos un mensaje!
          </h1>
          <h5 class="texto-azul roboto">
            Estaremos encantados de conocerte <br>¡Envíanos un mensaje y nos pondremos en contacto a la brevedad!
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="../script/enviar_msj.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-row mt-3">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="roboto texto-azul" for="nombre">Nombre*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="roboto texto-azul" for="apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="roboto texto-azul" for="email">Email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ejemplo@tudominio.cl" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="roboto texto-azul" for="telefono">Teléfono / celular</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="(+56) 9 12345678">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="roboto texto-azul" for="mensaje">Mensaje*</label>
          <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu mensaje" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row justify-content-center mt-4 mb-5">
          <button type="submit" name="btnenviar" id="btnenviar" class="btn boton-azul btn-lg">Enviar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--GOOGLE MAPS-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="texto-azul dosis">
            ¡Ven a visitarnos!
          </h1>
          <h5 class="texto-azul roboto">
            Encuéntranos en Av. Vicuña Mackenna #1703 o llámanos al <br> (+56) 22 9339129
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 mt-5">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Av.+vicuña+mackenna+1703&key=AIzaSyB9dp7IC5AMnJSMohu1y6_v_CqHLBDLgvI" allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<?php

  //nombrando campos
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
  $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

  //datos para el correo
  $destinatario = "xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.cl";
  $asunto = "Contacto Web: Tienes un mensaje de $nombre";
  $contenido = "De: $nombre $apellido \n";
  $contenido .= "Correo: $email \n";
  $contenido .= "Telefono: $telefono \n";
  $contenido .= "Mensaje: $mensaje \n";
  $contenido .= "¡RECUERDA RESPONDER AL REMITENTE!";

  //enviar Correo
  mail($destinatario, $asunto, $contenido);
  header('Location:gracias.php');
 ?>
```

Comment: has borrado cache del navegador?

Comment: probaste con otro navegador? , a que ruta apunta la imagen , dale click sobre ella y selecciona la opcion , inspeccionar elemento para ver su ruta, de repente , esta apuntando a otra carpeta en tu hosting

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser cosa de la caché. Prueba refrescando la página con ctrl + F5 a ver como va. A demás, yo siempre suelo utilizarlo, en el modo desarrollador de los navegadores, al menos chorme y firefox, hay una opción para que nunca te guarde la caché y evitar este tipo de conflictos.

Comment: Era un problema de cache, muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Con la consola de desarrollador del navegador. En Chrome. Haz clik derecho en el boto de recargar página, y te aparecerá la opción de vaciar cache y cargar forzada ente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente el problema es la **cache** del navegador.

### **¿Qué es la cache?**

Es una función propia de los navegadores que permite cargar las páginas web más rápido guardando en el ordenador parte de la información que previamente se ha solicitado.

**Ventajas:** Las páginas web que se ven todos los días cargarán mucho más rápido.

**Desventajas:** Puede llegar a ocupar mucho espacio, incluso a ocupar archivos que nunca más volverás a utilizar. Además, a nosotros como desarrolladores puede ocurrir que a veces hayamos realizado cambios en el diseño y no los veamos porque la página se está cargando desde la caché del navegador en lugar de volver a solicitar el archivo CSS o JS de cero.

Abajo muestro el flujo del cache la primera vez que entra a una página web.

1. Primero entra y solicita el archivo **default.aspx**, lo lee y encuentra un archivo JS.
2. Solicita el archivo al servidor web y lo lee.
3. Lo guarda en la cache del navegador.

[image: Flujo del cache la primera vez que entra a una página web.]

Ahora el flujo del cache después de la primera vez que ingreso a la misma página web.

1. Vuelve a solicitar el archivo **default.aspx**, lo lee y encuentra el mismo nombre de un archivo JS.
2. El cache piensa que es el mismo archivo que solicito la primera vez que entro a la página y decide que no es necesario solicitarlo al servidor web, y en su lugar añade el que esta en cache.

[image: Flujo del cache después de la primera vez que ingreso a la misma página web]

### **¿Cómo soluciono esa desventaja como desarrollador?**

La buena noticia es que hay muchas soluciones para el problema del cache.

**Extensiones/Addons**

Puedes utilizar la extensión [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=es) de Chrome para eliminar con un clic la cache o en [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/clearcache/).

**Cadena aleatoria**

Añadir una cadena aleatoria después del formato de tu archivo JS o CSS.

```
<script src="test.js?version=1"></script>
```

```js
let fakePath = new Date();
let fileName = 'scripts.js';

fakePath = fakePath.getTime();
console.log(fileName + '?random=' + fakePath);
```

**Borrar desde el navegador**

Puedes borrar directamente desde el navegador siguiendo las instrucciones de [Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es) y [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/limpia-la-cache-y-elimina-los-archivos-temporales-)

Y además estas otras soluciones ya dadas en [otro post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63724/12625) de SOEs.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, MUCHAS GRACIAS, justamente era un problema con el cache. Gracias por la pronta respuesta a todos.