# Forzar limpieza de cookies en los clientes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando  hago un nuevo reléase de una pagina web, noto que los navegadores/clientes siguen mostrando colores anteriores (cuando en el nuevo reléase los cambie en los archivos `CSS`).

Si vuelvo a cargar la pagina con **CTRL+F5** o **limpio cookies** en el browser cliente, puedo visualizar los nuevos cambios pero esto no me asegura que todas las personas que hayan entrado antes limpiaran las cookies también.

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de **forzar la limpieza de cookies** al implementar una **nueva versión** de la pagina web, para los cambios se vean reflejados de manera exitosa?

Comment: Las cookies no afectan al cargar hojas de estilo. Te recomiendo revisar [esta , pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63716/54039), te va a servir siempre y cuando actualices el valor de la variable cada que hagas cambios en tus CSS.

Comment: gracias @Triby es lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion facil es versionar tu CSS de la siguiente manera:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tuRuta.css?v=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tuRuta.css?v=1.1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tuRuta.css?v=1.2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tuRuta.css?v=1.3">
```

Cada vez que agregues una nueva vercion de tu CSS aumentas la versión `?v=+1` de esta manera te aseguras que que el cliente cargue siempre la ultima versión.