# Porque mi plantilla HTML no responde al archivo CSS en mi servidor Apache?

Tags: php, html, css, apache

En un proyecto (educativo) que tengo, usando el servidor Apache y PHP, me ha ocurrido el siguiente problema:

Mi documento index.php incluye a un fichero php que contiene una plantilla HTML(main.php) que esta ubicada en una carpeta inferior, llamada 'Visual', y en esa misma carpeta está el documento CSS que es utilizada por la plantilla HTML(main.css).

La primera vez que organicé la plantilla HTML con sus estilos CSS todo fue bien, pero después de guardar los archivos y apagar el servidor, al día después, al volver a conectar el servidor y querer hacer cambios en los estilos CSS, la plantilla HTML no respondía a los cambios hechos en main.css; sin embargo, al cambiar de nombre el archivo CSS y su respectiva invocación en la plantilla HTML, volvía a responder correctamente a los cambios hechos en el archivo CSS, sin cambiar su directorio, solo su nombre.

Acá dejare resumidos los dos archivos correspondientes

index.php:

```
    <?php
    include 'Visual\main.php';
    ?>
```

main.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Visual\main.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

*Aclaro que en la invocacion CSS en main.php se hace tomando referencia en index.php, ya que es desde alli donde se incluye a main.php. Por ello, la ruta es 'Visual\main.css' y no 'main.css'

Este es un problema que la verdad no entiendo, incluso si elimino el archivo CSS, la plantilla HTML no responde y sigue con los estilos definidos anteriormente.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63716).

Comment: Gracias Sal, problema resuelto. Si puedes, haz una respuesta para poder marcar mi pregunta como solucionada.

Answer (score 0):

En esta linea
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrégale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero te sirva

Comment: En vez de añadir imagenes, añade el codigo con su correspondiente formato, para que de esta forma sea mas legible y se pueda copiar y pegar si fuera necesario.