# Poner botón para refrescar cache en jquery / html / js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

he estado buscando en el buscador y no he encontrado una respuesta clara para mi. Lo que intento es que si yo hago un cambio en la programación de una web, los usuarios tengan la opción de poder refrescar la cache para que puedan ver los últimos cambios realizados. Pero no quiero que la cache se quede siempre a False, me interesa tener la cache activa para que la pagina cargue mas rápido.

En resumen, solo quiero refrescar cuando hago algún cambio.

He visto en algunos sitios esto:

const reload = document.getElementById('reload');

```
reload.addEventListener('click', _ => { 

 // borraCache();

    location.reload();
});

        <div class="fixed-bottom footer py-2 pl-3  pr-3"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="reload"  class="btn-smM   btn btn-outline btn-block " >Recargar</button>
            </div>
                    
        </div>
```

Pero creo no tengo claro que este código borre la cache.

He visto también esta función

```
  $.ajax({
 url:'www.haorooms.com',
 dataType:'json',
 data:{},
 cache:false, 
 ifModified :true ,

 success:function(response){
               //Operación
 }
 async:false
```

});

Esta función me da error en la linea async:false y cuando le pongo un alert en success para ver si ha funcionado, no me entra en el alert.

Comment: Te recomiendo ver [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63716/54039) y sus respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info pero por lo que he estado viendo, no me termia de servir. En mi caso, necesito que el usuario final, el que maneja la web, pueda borrar la cache mediante un botón o similar. Pero que una vez que la haya borrado, las siguientes veces si tire de la cahe.